# Repeat the previous observable

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that returns a promise. I want to catch error on this and then exponentially wait longer and retry. But for now I am just waiting a constant of 5s. Here is my code:

```
from(connectSocket()).pipe(
    catchError(e => {
        console.log('got error!', e.message);
        return timer(5000).pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('will repeat connect now')),
            repeat(1)
        );
    }),
    tap(() => setIsConnected.next(true))
);
```

However it does not repeat.

My full code is in this sandbox - https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g7msgv?file=index.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an exponential retry you'll need to use `retryWhen`. Heres an example:

```js
// will retry with
// 0, 10, 40, 90, 160 ms delays
retryWhen(error$ =>
  error$.pipe(
    delayWhen((_, i) => timer(i * i * 10))
  )
)
```

[image: exponential backoff]

**[Try this code in a playground](https://thinkrx.io/gist/d351a5b0c4be0e9dfe6c3a37ab050929)**

In your example you're **repeating** `timer`, instead of **retrying** `from(connectSocket())`. So substitute `catchError` with a `retryWhen` to get what you need.

Hope this helps

--

Also, there are 3rd party tools to add exponential backoff, e.g.
https://github.com/alex-okrushko/backoff-rxjs

See my **["Error handling in RxJS"](https://medium.com/@kddsky/error-handling-in-rxjs-bac0f96a7def)** article to get better understanding of errors and retries in RxJS.

Comment: This is an awesome solution, I really like your article on error handling. Thank you! I was wondering what the repeat was doing!

Comment: Oh gosh, I tried out this code, but it doesn't seem to redo the `connectSocket` it just straight throws the error again: https://i.imgur.com/3RWWvSX.png

Comment: It repeats the whole `exhaustMap` if I place the `retryWhen` after it, but I want to just repeat the `from(connectSocket())` - https://i.imgur.com/5eWwwBc.png

Comment: @Noitidart, hm, lets try then replace `from(connectSocket()).pipe(retryWhen(...))` with `of(null).pipe(switchMap(()=>connectSocket()), retryWhen(...))`

Comment: @Noitidart `defer(() => connectSocket())` should also work instead of `from(connectSocket())`. And just in case: also, ensure that `connectSocket()` creates a new promise each time, instead of returning the same one.

Comment: Wow so weird! It worked! Thank you! Just curious is it possible to make this code a bit cleaner -  https://i.imgur.com/0MEDVlZ.png - ideally I would like to avoid another `*Map`

Comment: Whoaaaa `defer` fixed up so i dont need that extra `*Map` inside with `of(null)` super cool I just learned 3 new operators. If possible if anything to help me better understand why `defer` did this and why things were happening, it would be awesome to hear. I'm just struggling understanding Rx lol.

Comment: @Noitidart `defer(() => connectSocket())` should also work, heres an example: https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/4efcae7ff575a3382a9ece0dbf77154b **EDIT**: oops :)

Comment: @Noitidart , please, see [standalone defer example](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/defer/). `defer` basically returns a promise when it's subscribed to. `retryWhen` will resubscribe to source once an error occurs. Thus once we hit an error -- `retryWhen` will resubscribe to `defer`, which in turn will call our function that returns promise again. Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is really helpful! I really like the observable-playground from the soution and your comment I had no idea about it. Hahaha that standalone defer example with bird icon is awesome!

Comment: Hey @kos I wanted to add a 2s delay before connectSocket, and when it fails, it should retry the 2s delay and then connectSocket. But I can't figure it out :( I tried all kind of things, the latest is this which works but its not the observable way :( https://i.imgur.com/91vpbEY.png

Comment: @Noitidart, heya! [retryWhen](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/retryWhen/) with [delayWhen](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/delayWhen/) should be enough for timeouts before retries. If you want to make an initial delay -- wrap it into `timeout(2s).switchMap(()=>` put your *defer.pipe(retryWhen)* here `)`. If you'll still got concerns -- please, create another question with some code sample. GL

Comment: Thanks @kos for replying even when not in another question. I'll post a question soon. My goal is to redo three things if any one of them fail. So I'm trying to stuff three things into that one `defer`.